# Force Excel Workbook evaluation before read.xlsx in R?

Tags: r, excel, r-xlsx

I am reading Excel Workbooks (.xlsx format) with `read.xlsx()` from the `xlsx` package. My Workbooks have dates stored as functions (e.g., `=DATE(1900, 1, 1)`) rather than strings or fractional days from 1899-12-31 (e.g., `1/1/1900` or `1`).

This is not a problem for `read.xlsx` if the Workbook has ever been opened/evaluated. But many of these Workbooks have never been opened/evaluated (they're generated by my data provider, not by Excel). Because the Workbook has not been opened/evaluated it contains -1 rather than the actual fractional number of days since 1899-12-31 (e.g., 37036 for May 25, 2001). I learned this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19412346/apache-poi-reading-date-from-excel-date-function-gives-wrong-date). So if I read a date in one of these (never opened) Workbooks, I get a column of -1, which `read.xlsx` interprets as 1899-12-30 (i.e., one day before 1899-12-31).

Is there a fix here? Can I `touch` a Workbook to force evaluation? Is there a bit that I can flip in `read.xlsx` to force evaluation first? I see only a `colClasses` argument, which doesn't seem to be the problem? Can I avoid using an Excel VBA script to write these Workbooks to text? Sorry I can't provide any reproducible code, but if you open an Excel Workbook to enter `=Date()`, the problem won't exist.

Comment: In case you cannot find a way to do this using `read.xlsx` the brute force way might be to open and save the files one by one programmatically using the `rcom` or `RDCOMClient` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `XLConnect` package , You can use :

```
getForceFormulaRecalculation(object,sheet)
```

to compute for all sheets :

```
getForceFormulaRecalculation(wb, sheet = "*")
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the `XLConnect` package. `readWorksheet` got the dates correct (i.e., forced evaluation first) and was faster for my use case.